# Custom Control in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

I create a custom AnchorPane (ItemCard) in JavaFX to use it in another FXML file.

ItemCard.fxml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane fx:id="ItemCardPane" prefHeight="360.0" prefWidth="266.0" stylesheets="@ItemCard.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">

            <children>
                <ImageView fx:id="ItemCardView" fitHeight="399.0" fitWidth="245.0" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="6.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
            </children>

        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

the controller of ItemCard is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ola
 */
public class ItemCard extends AnchorPane {

    @FXML
    ImageView ItemCardView;
    @FXML
    AnchorPane ItemCardPane;

    public ItemCard() {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ItemCard.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        ItemCardView.setImage(image);
//        getChildren().add(ItemCardView);
    }

}
```

i want to use this itemCard Anchore Pane in another fxml.
home.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import com.syrianep.reader.ui.KidsTheme.resources.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="home" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1000.0" prefWidth="1250.0" style="-fx-border-radius: 5; -fx-background-color: tranparant;" stylesheets="@mainView.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.syrianep.reader.ui.KidsTheme.resources.HomeController" >
    <children>
        <ItemCard layoutX="50.0" layoutY="50.0"AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0"/>  
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

but the problem that when i open home.fxml using scene builder the itemCard is not viewed.
error is;
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)

Comment: Do you get an error message also, and not just the procedure call where the error is? And what happens if you try to load the FXML that includes the custom control?

Comment: thanks i solve the problem. i use javafx with netbeans platform, so i should make the package of module as public package.